# Django no carga archivos estáticos en producción

Tags: python, django

Estoy utilizando Bitnami djangostack.
En desarrollo todo funciona correctamente. 
Pero en producción tengo que cambiar el settings.py para que funcionen las templates en cambios ya que los archivos `css` o `js` no son cargados.

```
"""
Django settings for Project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'h%@$8*%256p62ac-dv(kmq2gpeo8lza$90ana#oo9edmdh^1x2'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx','localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Project.urls'


#SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

"""

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'djangostack',
        'HOST': '/opt/bitnami/postgresql',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'ejemplo',
        'PASSWORD': 'ejemplo'
    }
}
"""

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

]
```

No sé si es necesario tocar el http-app en producción para que funcione.

```
<IfDefine !IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED> 
Define IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-djangostack   processes=2 threads=15    display-name=%{GROUP}
</IfDefine> 

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/Project">
    Options +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

    WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-djangostack

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Require all granted

</Directory>

Alias /Project/static "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.1.4-py3.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/static"
WSGIScriptAlias / '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/Project/wsgi.py'
```

He probado de todo pero no doy en el clavo. Llevo 2 días con el problema. A alguien se le ocurre algo?

Comment: Para ejecutar collectstatic he tenido que añadir STATIC ROOT EN setting STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

Comment: Y da como resultado 60 static files copied to '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/static', 63 unmodified. pero sige sin cargar CSS o JS en produccion

Comment: BINGO!! muchismas gracias. Ha funcionado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder usar los ficheros estaticos de Django, primero debes generarlo, ejecutando el comando:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Una vez finalizado el comando, te dira donde se genero la ruta seria algo como:

```
 60 static files copied to '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/static', 63 unmodified
```

y por ultimo debes darle acceso a tu servidor (en este caso Apache) para que pueda ver los archivos, Agrega a tu virtualhost algo como:

```
Alias /static " /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/static" 
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/static> 
  Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

> Puedes ver la  [documentacion de como generar los ficheros estaticos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)