# App Django en producción usando Wampserver + mod_wsgi, no se carga el contenido multimedia

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, wampserver

Desplegué mi aplicación Django usando Wampserver (apache 2.4) y mod_wsgi. La siguiente es mi configuración **Settings.py**

```
...
DEBUG = False

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), 
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'ImgDocs\\'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Importaciones')
MEDIA_URL = '/Importaciones/'
...
```

La siguiente es la configuración del archivo `httpd.config`

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/mesa_dco/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/mesa_dco/appdata/local/programs/python/python36"
WSGIScriptAlias / "R:/MyProject/MyProject/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "R:/MyProject"

Alias /static "R:/MyProject/staticfiles"
Alias /media "R:/MyProject/Importaciones"

<Directory "R:/MyProject/staticfiles">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "R:/MyProject/Importaciones">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "R:/MyProject/MyProject">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

La siguiente es la estructura de mi proyecto

```
apps/
templates/
Importaciones/
    ImgDocs/
    uploads/
        Documentos/
static/
    css/
    img/
    js/
    ckeditor/
    vendor/
    fonts
staticfiles/
    admin/
manage.py
MyProject/
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
```

Ejecuto `python manage.py collecstatic` para copiar todos mis archivos estáticos a la carpeta indicada en `STATIC_ROOT`.

Con estas configuraciones el contenido estático se carga correctamente pero el contenido multimedia subido por el usuario y que se guarda correctamente no se visualiza, **¿por qué?**

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Django no carga archivos estáticos en producción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/224074/django-no-carga-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-producci%c3%b3n)

Comment: esta esta para [gnu/linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/213025/28035)

Comment: No, ninguna responde a mi pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Ya va modificaste a el httpd.xonfig en vez de un virtualhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el error. En el archivo `httpd.config` el "Alias" debe llevar el mismo nombre de la carpeta donde se guardan los archivos multimedia, no necesariamente se debe llamar "media", así

```
Alias /Importaciones "R:/MyProject/Importaciones
```

Era simplemente eso.