# Error cargando archivos estáticos en Django para producción

Tags: python, django

He revisado las demás preguntas relacionadas a la mia y tampoco me ha dado solución. Estoy llevando mi proyecto de django a producción (para autoaprendizaje), para lo cual leí una configuración recomendada que trata de separar las configuraciones del settings.py en varios archivos (base.py,local.py,produccion.py). Antes de realizar estos cambios mi proyecto trabajaba correctamente, pero al reorganizar el settings.py como mencioné antes, dejaron de cargar los archivos estáticos en el template.
La consola muestra el siguiente error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 10, 2020 - 14:54:57
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'biblioteca.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[10/Aug/2020 15:02:19] "GET /Biblioteca/Home HTTP/1.1" 200 5455
**[10/Aug/2020 15:02:19] "GET /static/assets/css/theme-4.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1692
[10/Aug/2020 15:02:19] "GET /static/assets/images/profile.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1701**
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[10/Aug/2020 15:02:21] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2086
```

Con el error 404 de las lineas resaltadas entiendo que no se encuentran los archivos.
Mi árbol de directorios está así:

```
raíz
    apps
    biblioteca
        settings
             base.py
             local.py
             production.py
    static
        assets
             css
               hojas de estilos.....
    Templates
    manage.py
```

Archivo base.py

```
    """
    Django settings for biblioteca project.
    
    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.
    
    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/
    
    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
    """
    
    import os
    
    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    
    
    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/
    
    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = 'cnbjxd3iils4xvf!o*u(rk$arocvk3_9lw!ho-tj^*q91qlpd#'
    
    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True
    
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    
    
    # Application definition
    
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'bootstrap4',
        'widget_tweaks',
        'rest_framework',
        'crispy_forms',
        'apps.libro',
    ]
    CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK='bootstrap4'
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
    
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'biblioteca.urls'
    
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': ['Templates'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
    
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'biblioteca.wsgi.application'
    
    
    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
    
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]
    
    
    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/
    
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-ec'
    
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Lima'
    
    USE_I18N = True
    
    USE_L10N = True
    
    USE_TZ = True

Archivo local.py
from .base import *
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'biblioteca',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306
    }
}


#  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT='static'
```

El de producción no lo agrego ya que no lo estoy usando ya que estoy usando el local.py

Archivo wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for biblioteca project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'biblioteca.settings.local')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Archivo manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'biblioteca.settings.local')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Para cargar los archivos estáticos en los template lo hago de la siguiente manera (coloco solo la porción de código necesaria):

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>{% block titulo %} Página Principal {% endblock titulo %}</title>
   {% load bootstrap4  %}

   {% bootstrap_css  %}
   <link  href="{% static "assets/css/theme-4.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

No se cual es el error, cualquier sugerencia se agradece

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Django no carga archivos estáticos en producción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/224074/django-no-carga-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-producci%c3%b3n)

Comment: @JulioCesar también genere o realizé python manage.py collecticstatic pero no me funcionó, como mencioné al principio, he revisado las preguntas relacionadas y no me han solucionado el error.

Comment: Incluye el archivo `settings.local`. `STATIC_ROOT` debe ser absoluto.

Comment: @loki si te refieres al settings.py, ese archivo lo eliminé, ya que lo que contenía lo distribuí en los archivos base.py local.py production.py

Comment: Entonces porque lo tienes en el manage.py?

Comment: @loki  que hago en manage.py es llamar a mi carpeta settings que contiene el local.py en el cual está definido la ruta para los archivos estáticos, antes de modificarlo estaba como `biblioteca.settings` donde settings era mi archivo que contenia todas las configuraciones, pero ahora lo tengo en el archivo local.py entonces llamo a `bibioteca.settings.py` donde settings es la carpeta que contiene a local.py

Comment: Agregaste las rutas al url.py??

Comment: from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: Dónde estás haciendo el Hosting, dónde está el Deploy de Aplicaciones Django.??

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar el problema del CSS y demás, es decir archivos estáticos, se tiene que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Instala whitenoise. En el terminal del proyecto (la que tienes de forma local) escribir esto: pip install whitenoise
2. Agregarlo a la configuración de settings.py. En el archivo de configuración presionar Control + F para que aparezca la barra de búsqueda y escribir esto MIDDLEWARE. Les llevara al apartado donde se encuentra este código, buscar y colocar debajo de 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware' colocar este código: 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', (no olvidar las comillas y la coma del final).
3. Buscar la configuración del manejo de archivos estáticos, deben encontrar algo como esto:

   ```
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
   STATICFILES_DIRS=[BASE_DIR / "static",]
   ```

   Debajo de esa linea colocar lo siguiente:

   ```
   STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
   ```
4. Agregar al archivo requirements.txt la nueva librería instalada que es whitenoise, esto es importante para que el servidor también pueda ejecutarlo.
5. Probar de forma local que todo funcione.
6. Realizar add y commit, con ello ya les debe cargar los estilos y demás cosas de archivos estáticos.
7. Probar en el servidor.

El problema radica en como el servidor de producción obtiene este tipo de archivos y por lo que es más fácil configurarlo con whitenoise. Espero haberles ayudado con esto! Lleve muchas horas de investigación para solucionarlo, me siento contento de haber aprendido y aún soy novato en estos temas pero dejo mi grano de arena por aquí. Podría grabar un pequeño video tutorial de como lo solucione si lo piden muchos.

Si quieren mayor información lo obtendrán de aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment
https://dev.to/osahenru/using-railway-app-to-deploy-your-django-project-3ah1/comments

Answer (score 0):

Probaste agregar las static al url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: si, también agregué eso, al final opté por dejar todo en el mismo archivo. No se porque no funcionó de esa manera de separar en archivos si al final solo se modificaba la ruta.

Comment: Esto es algo muy común que pase en Django. Cuando pasas el código a producción los static no funcionan, debe hacerse un collectstatic. Si tienes algun error en el collectstatic por favor compartenos. Después del collectstatic no olvides reiniciar gunicorn si lo estas usando. Este problema es tan común que en la página de django tienen un apartado para esto https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: Mi consejo es no te desanimes. Compartenos tus avances. Al menos yo batalle mucho con esto pero se aprende mucho resolviendolo.

Comment: Gracias, si igual había intentado hacer el collecstatic; y si, continúo explorando Django, me parece muy interesante, y seguro que con mas experiencia podré resolver esto que en su momento no se dio. Gracias.

Comment: Que servidor usas??? checaste la configuracion del servidor a las carpetas static y root?? si es nginx puedo compartirte un ejemplo